# Git (SSH) hangs during clone/push/pull

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

Whenever I try and perform an operation using `git` (e.g. `clone`, `pull`, or `push`) over SSH the git client seems to hang and time out indefinitely (I've left it running for half an hour to no avail). I have my SSH keys loaded (using BitBucket). I am able to perform anything I need via HTTPS, and SSH is the only thing that appears to break.

Here is some console output from an attempted pull

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git pull
16:44:05.679911 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'pull'
16:44:05.681453 run-command.c:334       trace: run_command: 'fetch' '--update-head-ok'
16:44:05.686650 exec_cmd.c:120          trace: exec: 'git' 'fetch' '--update-head-ok'
16:44:05.697849 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'fetch' '--update-head-ok'
16:44:05.703211 run-command.c:334       trace: run_command: 'ssh' '-p' '7999' 'git@git.myCompany.com' 'git-upload-pack '\''/ei/myProject.git'\'''
```

Anyone have any idea what could be happening?

Comment: Can you manually connect via `ssh -p 7999 git@git.myCompany.com`? If not, there might be a firewall dropping your packages.

Comment: @sauerburger `ssh -p 7999 git@git.myCompany.com
Shared connection to git.myCompany.com closed.`

If I follow @VonC's response with forwarding, I get prompted for a username/password.

Answer (score 1):

7999 is a non-standard port which is likely to be blocked.

If port 22 is not blocked (and that is a big if), then you can consider [an ssh tunneling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6284078/6309):

```
ssh -R 7999:localhost:22  git@git.myCompany.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a machine where git is working, you can compare the
ssh configuration file of the nonworking to the working machine.

The ssh config file is located at `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

In my case, git was working fine on Windows but not WSL2. In windows the port was set to 22 while in WSL2 it was set to 2200. I changed it to 22 and was able to continue using git on wsl2.